# Unable to use MomentJS in NodeJS when creating a custom visual for PowerBI

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, momentjs, powerbi

I am building a custom-visual for Power BI, but I am not sure if that is relevant to this question of if my problem is more general.

Anyway, the custom-visual is built using Node.js and typescript and using custom libraries should be no problem ([link](https://github.com/Microsoft/PowerBI-visuals/blob/master/Tutorial/ExternalLibraries.md)).

However when I have added momentjs, my script sort of "hangs" as soon as I try to use it. I don't get an error message or exception or anything else. Using the lines below

```
console.log('Trying moment.js');
console.log(moment);
console.log('Moment-testing success');
```

it "stops" after outputting `Trying moment.js`.

These are the steps i have taken to install momentjs:

1. Ran `npm install momentjs --save`
2. Added `"node_modules/moment/moment.d.ts"` under `files` in my `tsconfig.json`. From my understanding, the moment.d.ts is sort of a "header"-file which only is used for autocompelte/InteliJ in my IDE, i.e. it does only include the declaration of functions, not the definition. As soon as I add this line my IDE stops complaining about not finding `moment`.
3. Added `"node_modules/moment/moment.js"` to my `pbiviz.json` under `externalJS` ([link](https://github.com/Microsoft/PowerBI-visuals-sampleBarChart/blob/master/pbiviz.json))
4. Added `"moment": "^2.19.1",` under `dependencies` in the `package.json`.

Is there something I have missed? It feels like my application cant find the actual moment.js and resolve what `moment` is...

Comment: Did you require/import moment where this is being executed?